# What does qt in bitcoin-qt stand for?

Tags: bitcoin-core

just a simple question: what does qt in bitcoin-qt stand for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework for developers using C++. It's is used for UI in Bitcoin-Qt. See http://qt-project.org/

Comment: it could be useful to add the link to : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29

Answer (score 3):

According to the Wikipedia article:"The toolkit was called Qt because the letter Q looked appealing in Haavard's Emacs font, and "t" was inspired by Xt, the X toolkit"